# CSS Selectors Explanation

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm really confused as to how I can style this list WITHOUT changing the following HTML or wrapping it in class names. How do I go about this?

For example, if I want to put Ocean Fish in bold but NOT have Pacific or Atlantic affected, how do I target that div without adding a class name?

Another example, I want to have "12 salmon" and "3 cod" in green text, and "46 halibut" and "13 pollock" in blue text? in I know there's a trick using very specific selectors, but I don't know how.

````
 <ul>
   <li>
     <div>Ocean Fish</div>
     <ul>
       <li>
         <div>Pacific</div>
         <ul>
           <li>12 salmon</li>
           <li>3 cod</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
       <li>
         <div>Atlantic</div>
         <ul>
           <li>46 halibut</li>
           <li>13 pollock</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>```
````

Comment: You can use [tree structural pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#tree-structural_pseudo-classes) for this.   I Recommend `class` attributes instead though.   After all,  is pacific  fish supposed to be green,  or the first li in a ul in a ul?  You don't have to "wrap" anything; add the class to one of the existing elements

Comment: Besides the classes being more readable, tree structure selectors are a _pain_ to maintain. If you ever change your tree structure... _pain_.

Comment: definitely a pain. this question came up on a class quiz and i was stumped-- i don't think this question is meant for best practice!

Comment: Note that sometimes you don't have a choice - for example, when making a browser extension that targets a web page that you don't have control over.

Comment: interesting, thank you. i'm new to this (on week 3 of learning html/css) so i'm open to all the info i can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will handle all your cases if you want to do it without classes.

```
body > ul > li > div{font-weight:bold;}
body > ul > li > ul:nth-child(2) > li > ul{color:green;}
body > ul > li > ul:nth-child(3) > li > ul{color:blue;}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! i was wracking my brain... this worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Similar method to previous answer, but more direct:

```
 let divSel = document.querySelectorAll('div');  // alert(divSel.length);
 divSel[0].style.fontWeight = 'bolder';

 let liSel = document.querySelectorAll('li');
 liSel[2].style.color = 'green';
 liSel[3].style.color = 'green';
 liSel[5].style.color = 'blue';
 liSel[6].style.color = 'blue';
```

Still a pain to modify if entry order is changed.

Comment: how would i format this on a css stylesheet? i'm trying to test it out but it's not working :(

Comment: It is not done in the CSS stylesheet.  It is done on the DOM level with JS only and relates to the HTML in the 1st post.